# Laravel How to increment only when its a new insert?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I need to increment 'total_products' field in Categories table every time a new product is added. But I don't want it to increase when an existing product is UPDATED. I'm doing this right now:

```
Category::findOrNew($product->cat_id)->increment('total_products',1);
```

But this code doesn't recognize whether its an update or a new insert. It increases 'total_products' no matter its an insert or update. How can I make it increment only when its a new insert?

Comment: do you want to increment on update or new ?

Comment: It should increment only when its a completely new insert, i.e., when a new product is added to the catalogue. If I'm only updating an existing product, then the count should NOT increase.

Comment: don't need to increment, update you table schema, and make `total_products` value 1 as default. `ALTER TABLE category ALTER COLUMN total_products SET DEFAULT '1';`

Comment: I think you have mixed, product and category, Please be clear ? do you want to increment `category` on new `product` insert ?

Answer (score 2):

It is clearly two query, try each with separate query

```
$cat = Category::find($product->cat_id);
if($cat){
    $cat->increment('total_products',1);
}else{
    $cat = new Category();
    $cat->total_products = 1;
    // Inert new category here with all related data
    $cat->save(); 
}
return $cat->id;
```

Also be sure about when to increase `total_products` ? `after insert` or `after update`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `firstOrCreate` method for that:

```
$category = Category::firstOrCreate(['name' => 'John Doe']);
```

If you want to know whether the user was created or fetched, check the wasRecentlyCreated property:

```
if ($category->wasRecentlyCreated) {
    // "firstOrCreate" didn't find the user in the DB, so it created it.
} else {
    // "firstOrCreate" found the user in the DB and fetched it.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `total_products` field to 0 by default in the migration:

```php
$table->integer('total_products')->default(0);
```

Then `findOrCreate` and `increment`:

```php
Category::query()
    ->findOrCreate($product->cat_id)
    ->increment('total_products');
```